# How to fix inconsistent rendering results caused by adding frame animation to character spacing?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, text-object

After I ended the character spacing frame animation, the text seemed to render differently.

The first image I added shows the rendering before the end of the "character spacing" animation, and the second image shows the rendering after the end of the "character spacing" animation (the two circled characters seem to be slightly different).

My English is not very good and I apologize if any trouble is caused by poor expression!

[image]
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image]

Comment: can you pls add a blend file so that we can help you?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I added the blend file! It would have made the file size larger than 30mb if I had added the shading, so I gave up on packing the data.